# Finding characters of a word in a string, optimized

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I am doing doing a few code challenges in the hope to learn some new stuff. Currently I have written a piece of code that find charachter of a given word in a string of random letters.

I thought regexp might be the best performance-wise (it's one of the objectives). This code passes the checks but takes too long with absurd long strings. Is there any way I can improve this? It's really ugly as is honestly. I've tried several approaches but I am probably just really a newbie at reg exp etc.

before all the if statements I only used regexp but if str2 which is the word I am looking for had double characters it would come back 'true' because it would count already counted characters. That is why I am using replace to exclude them. That's all I could get.

the goal is to return true if a portion of str1 can be rearranged to form str2, otherwise return false. Only lower case letters will be used (a-z). No punctuation or digits will be included. for example scramble('aabbcamaomsccdd','commas') should return true

```
function scramble (str1, str2)
{
var o = 0; // tracks amount of matched letters.
 for(i = 0; i < str2.length; i++)
 {
    var regex1 = new RegExp (str2[i]) ; // select letter from word that needs to be found
    if( regex1.test(str1) == true)// if selected character is found us replace to remove it from the random characters string for next iteration.
    {
      str1 = str1.replace(regex1 ,"");
      o++; // increment o if character is removed from random string.
    }
 }
//check if amount of removed characters equals total characters of word that we want.
    if ( o == str2.length)
    {
      return true
    }
    if (o !== str2.length)
    {
      return false
    }
}
```

Update: I flagged the hash table as answer because afaik this was not doable with regexp it seems also I was able to achieve a proper result with .split and loops myself plus the hash table also achieved this.

Comment: what is the objective of the code? do you have an example and the wanted outcome?

Comment: Return true if a portion of str1 can be rearranged to form str2, otherwise return false.

Comment: I added a bit to the post hope this shows what the goal of the code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a hash table, count the wanted characters and return if no count is not more necessary.

```js
function scramble (str1, str2) {
    var counter = {},
        keys = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
        if (!counter[str2[i]]) {
            counter[str2[i]] = 0;
            keys++;
        }
        counter[str2[i]]++;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        if (!counter[str1[i]]) continue;
        if (!--counter[str1[i]] && !--keys) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(scramble('abc', 'cba'));
console.log(scramble('abc', 'aba'));
console.log(scramble('abcdea', 'aba'));
console.log(scramble('aabbcamaomsccdd', 'commas'));
```

Comment: This passes the long string cases, I thought there might be a way to make a regexp constructor and add the characters and the amount of each character in a string each time. Not sure if thats even a thing. I will need to look into hastables I guess not really familiar with them.

Comment: I will flag this as an answer if there is no regexp suggestion soon since that was what I thought the purpose of the challenge was. It works, is "faster" than my solution and gave me something else to learn/look into. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if-less methodology!

i didnt stress it on tests but looks fine

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  str1 = [...str1];
  return [...str2].filter((str => (str == str1.splice(str1.indexOf(str), 1)))).join('') == str2;

}
```

Comment: I wish this would work but the indexOf together with the other methods are killing it on the long string cases I think. Nice answer though gave me some ideas. This is the challenge I am working on if you want to have a look at the results. https://www.codewars.com/kata/scramblies/train/javascript